# Cannot "kern back" after applying kerning

Tags: spacing, kerning

Usually when I apply kerning to a pair of characters, I undo the kerning by adding the negative of the kerning afterwards, i.e. `{x}\kern1em\{y}\kern-1em` (cf. [Move a combining character with both \raisebox and \kern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83805/move-a-combining-character-with-both-raisebox-and-kern)).

But in this case, I cannot undo the kerning. If I add the negative of the kerning afterwards, the following character is pushed away, but if I don't add it, the following character is drawn towards the previous character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newcommand{\longa}{\char"0101}
\newcommand{\myacute}{\char"00B4}
\newcommand{\stressedlonga}{\longa\kern-.35em\raisebox{.35ex}{\myacute}\kern.35em}
\newcommand{\newstressedlonga}{\longa\kern-.35em\raisebox{.35ex}{\myacute}}
\begin{document}
\noindent{\stressedlonga}a\\ % characters are too far apart
aa\\ % this is the correct spacing between two characters
{\newstressedlonga}a % characters are too close together
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

---

egreg is suggesting what I first attempted here, which was to add the combining acute accent `U+0301` rather than the full-width character `U+00B4`. For reasons I fail to understand, however, as soon as I attempt to modify the placement of `U+0301` (which I want to do in order to match `U+1E53`), the accent shifts rightwards, and nothing I do will make it move back. In the example below, I'm not kerning the accent at all, yet it shifts rightwards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newcommand{\longa}{\char"0101}
\newcommand{\combiningacute}{\char"0301}
\newcommand{\stressedlonga}{\longa\raisebox{-.1ex}{\combiningacute}}

\begin{document}
\noindent{\stressedlonga}{\char"1E53}\\
{\longa\combiningacute}{\char"1E53}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The placement of combining characters is decided by the font designer.

Comment: Sure. That default placement is seen in the lower example. But why does it shift rightwards when I try to lower it with ``raisebox``- and why can't I move it leftwards again by adding kerning? In the question I link to, the default placement of the combining characters is off, but I have no difficulties modifying it with ``\kern`` and ``\raisebox`` - so what's going on in this case?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is quite difficult. You can avoid adding manual kerning for compensating the superimposed accent, but you'll lose the normal kerning anyway.

TeX (like other typesetting systems) automatically applies kern between pairs of characters such as `o` and `v`; with Computer Modern fonts the width resulting from `ov` is 10pt, while the sum of the widths of the characters is 10.27782pt.

Solving the problem in full generality would mean doing a lookahead after each character in order to see whether `\stressedlonga` follows and, after this constructed character, a lookahead to see what letter follows, all in order to apply the kern that would be applied if the simple `a` were to be typeset.

Leaving the general problem alone, here's a solution for `\stressedlonga` that doesn't require knowing the width of the glyphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newcommand{\longa}{\char"0101}
\newcommand{\myacute}{\char"00B4}
\newcommand{\stressedlonga}{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{##\cr
            \hidewidth\char"00B4\hidewidth\cr
            \noalign{\kern-1ex}
            \char"0101\cr}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\stressedlonga a\\
aa
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can fine tune the placement of the accent by adding some kern: if you change the line

```
\hidewidth\char"00B4\hidewidth\cr
```

into

```
\hidewidth\kern0.05em\char"00B4\hidewidth\cr
```

you get

[image]

Of course there's always the possibility of using combining characters; I'll use the `^^^^` convention for inputting U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT:

```
ā^^^^0301
```

produces

[image]

---

#### Some words on `\ialign`

The basic TeX function for alignments is `\halign` which of course is available also in LaTeX, being a primitive. Like LaTeX uses `\tabcolsep` for adding intercolumn space, `\halign` uses the value of `\tabskip`. Both Plain TeX and LaTeX define a wrapper around `\halign` to ensure `\tabskip` is zero:

```
% latex.ltx, line 494:
\def\ialign{\everycr{}\tabskip\z@skip\halign} % initialized \halign
```

The token parameter `\everycr` can contain material that's added between every row of the alignment (also before the first and after the last rows), so it's reset to empty. Of course, `\ialign` should be used in a group.

The syntax of `\halign` is rather complex: it must be followed by `{` and the material up to the first `\cr` is a list of `&`-separated *templates*. For instance, when one specifies a `c` column in a `tabular`, LaTeX basically inserts the template `\hfil#\hfil`, where `#` represents the cell's contents.

In our case the template is the minimal one, just `#` (that must be doubled because it appears in a definition). This means that we have only one row; no filling is necessary, because we'll have just two rows and the second one will determine the column width.

The first row of the alignment contains

```
\hidewidth\char"00B4\hidewidth\cr
```

that is, an acute accent that will be centered with respect to the column width; `\hidewidth` is a big negative skip with infinite stretchability, so it will never influece the computation of the widest cell. The `\cr` ends the row.

Next comes

```
\noalign{\vskip-1ex}
```

which means: “between the rows backup by 1ex”, which normally is the distance from the base of the accent to the baseline (minus some clearance). This length should be adjusted on a font basis, but it's easy to examine the result and act consequently.

The next row contains only the “long a” and the alignment ends.

We place the `\ialign` inside a `\vbox`, so that the baseline of the last row in the alignment will be the baseline of the box. This box is necessary because `\halign` is illegal in horizontal mode. The width of the `\vbox` will be the same as the width of the `\halign` inside it. In the `\vbox` we set `\offinterlineskip` to turn off TeX's usual computation of the interline space, so nothing will be added and we can control the spacing between the rows with `\noalign{\vskip...}`.

The initial `\leavevmode` is necessary for making sure TeX starts a paragraph in case `\stressedlonga` comes first.

Comment: I actually tried to use the combining accent ``U+0301`` first, but I ran into a weird problem I wasn't able to solve. See my updated question.

Comment: @Sverre If you don't like the combining character placement, use the `\ialign` macro.

Comment: A google search for "latex ialign" didn't give me anything I was able to use for knowing how to use that macro, and it's not in the official latex2e reference folder. Any pointers?

Comment: @Sverre That's low level TeX. Matter for wizards and gurus. `;-)`

Comment: But didn't you just advice me to use it? ``:P`` Now I feel like you're warning me against it ...

Comment: @Sverre It's not dangerous and you can learn how to use `\ialign` (basically `\halign` with a setting of zero `\tabskip`) by reading the TeXbook or TeX by Topic.

Comment: That by itself is all I need to know to realize I won't understand it. I don't even understand most of the package documentations out there. To put a different spin on it: would you care to add an example of how to modify the alignment of ``U+0301`` over ``U+0101`` with ``\ialign``? If I can make sense of that, I can use that as my template.

Comment: @Sverre I don't think combining characters work well when used by themselves.

Comment: "When used by themselves"?

Answer (score 6):

add `\showoutput` and you will see

```
....\kern -3.50006
....\hbox(8.35255+0.0)x3.33008
.....\hbox(6.78711+0.0)x3.33008, shifted -1.56544
......\EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/10 ´
....\EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/10 a
```

you are back spacing -3.5pt but the box is only 3.33pt wide

As noted in comments you want something like

```
\newcommand{\stressedlonga}{\longa\llap{\raisebox{.35ex}{\myacute}\kern.1em}}
```

Comment: And what does that mean?

Comment: @Sverre it means where did you get the value of .35em from?

Comment: By manually exploring what kerning value would put the acute accent in the middle of the macron.

Comment: @Sverre try `\newcommand{\stressedlonga}{\longa\llap{\raisebox{.35ex}{\myacute}}}`

Comment: Unfortunately that placement of the accent doesn't match the font's characters that have a unicode specification for macron+acute already. If you look at ``{\longa\llap{\raisebox{.35ex}{\myacute}}}{\char"1E53}``, you'll see that the accent should be further to the left over the 'a' character. I still don't understand why adding the negative of the kerning doesn't undo the kerning, though ...

Comment: @Sverre inside the llap you can add additinonal kerns before or after the raisebox, they'll move the accent without moving anything else `\newcommand{\stressedlonga}{\longa\llap{\raisebox{.35ex}{\myacute}\kern.1em}}`

Comment: Your first one has total kern 0pt so adds the width of the box (of the accent) your second one more or less negative compensates for the width of the accent but is not exact and so you over compensate by .17pt llap in my version ensures the accent takes up no horizontal space

Comment: Ok, I don't understand this ... what's the difference between what I am doing here and what I'm doing in the question I linked to?

Comment: `\char"0302` has zero width but the character you are adding now has width

Comment: Please see my updated question which shows what happened when I tried to add a combining character with zero width.

Comment: @Sverre using a kern inside llap as in my comment above you can position the accent wheerver you like

Comment: Do I need to use the accent with character width then?

Comment: @Sverre as in your original question, with the definition I give above just change the kern.1em to position as you want

Comment: I did, and it worked fine. I was just curious if the ``\llap`` + kerning solution is tied to characters with width.

Comment: @Sverre not really